# Throbber of Doom in Chrome/Safari

Tags: javascript, webkit, comet, throbber

Is there any way in JavaScript to Stop throbber of doom in Chrome/Safari browsers, when using push technology (Ajax Comet) with iframe.

Comment: might help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1064782/stop-the-browser-throbber-of-doom-while-loading-comet-server-push-iframe

Comment: possible duplicate of [Chrome's loading indicator keeps spinning during XMLHttpRequest](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2703861/chromes-loading-indicator-keeps-spinning-during-xmlhttprequest)